# async loading javascript with document.write

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous

I am trying to async the google map api javascript.

So, the normal script tag works `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

But, the following async version doesn't.

```
(function () {
    var gmap = document.createElement('script'); gmap.type = 'text/javascript'; gmap.async = true;
    gmap.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gmap, s);
})();
```

After some breakpoint+inspect action, I found out that this line doesn't run properly in the async mode.

```
document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"' + 
' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');
```

The document object in the sync mode is a "HTMLDocument", but in the async mode is a "#document" instead. Something happened to the document object after the page is loaded. Thoughts?

Cheers.

**Update:** this question is more about why document.write is not fired rather than async load the google map api. If you set a breakpoint on this line, you can see document.write function exists. Does this have anything to do with the fact that document.write is native?

Answer (score 8):

`document.write` can't be called from an asynchronous script, because it's detached from the document and therefore your JS parser doesn't know where to put it.  at best, the browser will ignore it.  at worst, it could write over the top of your current document (as in the case of calling document.write after the document has finished loading).

Unfortunately the only answer is to rewrite the script, which in the case of a google api is probably not a viable option.

Comment: Thanks. I did breakpoint on this line and try to document.write myself. It did find the write() function and that's why it's weird. If the write function is detached, then why is it not undefined?

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into a very similar problem when asynchronously loading amazon ads.  I was able to get `document.write` approximated in my app for these situations by changing its behavior (`$` in this case refers to jQuery):

```
document.write = function(content) {
  if (document.currentScript) {
    var src = document.currentScript.src
        .replace(/\#.*$/, '')
        .replace(/\?.*$/, '')
        .replace(/^.*\/\//, '');
    setTimeout(function() {
      var script = $('script').filter(function() {
        var scriptSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        return scriptSrc && scriptSrc.indexOf(src) !== -1;
      });
      $('<div></div>')
          .addClass('doc-write')
          .html(content)
          .insertAfter(script);
    }, 0);
  } else {
    HTMLDocument.prototype.write.apply(document, arguments);
  }
};
```

This approach could be improved on, but it works well enough for my needs.  Hopefully you will find it useful.

Comment: Just up voted this, but realized now this isn't support in IE 11. Any suggestions?

Comment: use the `callback=somefunction` param with initial api load

Answer (score 2):

When you use the parameter `callback` inside the script-URL, the script doesn't use `write()` and you'll be able to load the API asynchronously.

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#asynch

Comment: yeah, I had the callback but I ran into another problem in jquery mobile, where it's loading google map api multiple times. I didn't like the warning message.

Comment: When you don't like the warning don't load the API multiple times.

Comment: It's jquery mobile in asp mvc using the jqm ajax mode. So it just seem cleaner to load the API once rather than using the jqm events.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `document.write()`, for the reasons explained by market and Dr Molle. Use `appendChild()` instead, as done in [**Google's example of async loading**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async).

Comment: No more "map-simple-async". Only "map-simple". So this answer is not useful anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Adding a comment here since I struggled a fair bit with this problem. When loading the script asynchronously (via a button click for example), make sure you follow the instructions **exactly** as on the [site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#asynch).

I first got the `document.write` error when I didn't give the callback value. And after giving the callback, I got the `window.initialize` error because ... duh ... there was no initialize function in my code. I changed that to my function name (something like loadMap) and it started working.

To be honest, just copy the code from the site and it should work. Replace `window.onload` with whatever you need to trigger the said function.