# Require JS, Google Geocoding - same-origin Issue

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, requirejs, geocoding

**What I'm doing and what I've tried**

I'm using Google Geo coding web service to get the latitude and longitude of an address I pass, like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Boston&sensors=true",function(data){
    //Do my programming here
});
```

It was, for some reason working perfectly, initially, but then it stopped working and and I discovered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921745/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-to-google-maps-api) was the issue, that is using Google client side API.

I also read the answer on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921745/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-to-google-maps-api) SO question, which says the `<script>` tags help get over the cross site scripting issue.

**My problem :**

I'm using RequireJs, so I include the files like this :

```
var Google = require("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false");
```

So, how do I get my Google API working again and how do I do that with requireJS

Comment: Just a note that `$.getJSON("string", function(data){ }` needs a closing `);`

Comment: @Kriem , thanks for pointing it out , but that was just a typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requirejs will load the Maps-API asynchronous, but the URL you have used cannot be used for asynchronous loading(see [async loading javascript with document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003644/async-loading-javascript-with-document-write/13004230#13004230)) .

**What to do:** add the callback-parameter to the URL to be able to load the Maps-API asynchronously and execute the google-maps-related code in a function with a name equal to the value of the provided `callback`-parameter.

```
function geocodeaddr(){
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'Boston' }, function (results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
         }
         else {
            console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
         }
      });
}
require(["http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=geocodeaddr"]);
```