# javascript <script async attribute>

Tags: javascript

I am developing a widget.
the code for it is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hashgurus_woeid = 1;
</script>
<script src="../feed/livetrend.js"></script>
```

livetrend.js contains:

```
var _html = '<div id="FJ_TF_Cont" style="position: relative; padding: 20px; margin: 20px; border-width: 0px; width: 200px;">'
+ '<iframe width="210" height="640" src="../feed/default.aspx?woeid=' + hashgurus_woeid +'" ' 
+ 'name="FJIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 210px; border-width: 0px; z-index: 1;">'
+ '</iframe>'
+ '</div>';

document.write(_html);
```

test html page:

I created a test html page and put the widget in it. It perfectly works.
Now the whole problem is when i add the async attribute. i donot see any output.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hashgurus_woeid = 1;
</script>
<script async src="../feed/livetrend.js"></script>
```

what is the problem ? is it because of the document.write ?

Comment: "is it because of the document.write ?" Yes, exactly. *Don't use `document.write`*.

Comment: what should i do? what is the solution. I want to use async attribute. how will i rewrite my livetrend.js then? I am clueless

Comment: Why do you want to use async?

Comment: cause, I am making the widget go live and it may be used by many. I dont want my code to choke others program. I want my code to load  async.

Comment: See also: [*async loading javascript with document.write*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003644/async-loading-javascript-with-document-write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write` cannot be called from an asynchronous script. Use a regular script and an asynchronous injection of the HTML instead, e.g.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = "FJ_TF_Cont";
div.style.position = 'relative';
div.style.padding = '20px';
div.style.margin = '20px';
div.style.borderWidth = 0;
div.style.width = '200px';
var div.innerHTML = '<iframe width="210" height="640" src="../feed/default.aspx?woeid=' + hashgurus_woeid +'" ' 
+ 'name="FJIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 210px; border-width: 0px; z-index: 1;">'
+ '</iframe>';

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

If you want to insert at the point of the script, you can use:

HTML -

```
<script async data-hashgurus-woeid="1" id="live-trend-widget" src="../feed/livetrend.js"></script>
```

Javascript-

```
var liveTrendWidget = document.getElementById('live-trend-widget');

var hashGurusWoeId = liveTrendWidget.getAttribute("data-hashgurus-woeid");

var widgetDiv = document.createElement('div');
widgetDiv.id = "FJ_TF_Cont";
widgetDiv.style.position = 'relative';
widgetDiv.style.padding = '20px';
widgetDiv.style.margin = '20px';
widgetDiv.style.borderWidth = 0;
widgetDiv.style.width = '200px';
widgetDiv.innerHTML = '<iframe width="210" height="640" src="../feed/default.aspx?woeid=' + hashGurusWoeId +'" ' 
+ 'name="FJIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 210px; border-width: 0px; z-index: 1;">'
+ '</iframe>';

// Inserts BEFORE the script element
liveTrendWidget.parentElement.insertBefore(widgetDiv, liveTrendWidget);

// *** OR ***

// Inserts AFTER the script element
liveTrendWidget.parentElement.insertBefore(widgetDiv, liveTrendWidget.nextSibling);
```

See [getAttribute method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) and [insertBefore method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).

Comment: thanks. document.body.appendChild(div) - where will this append? I want this exactly where i called the <script src="../feed/livetrend.js"></script>

Comment: Updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: i still have to remove my async to make this work. otherwise it adds it to the bottom. :-( may be because of async it finishes processing last and so it adds to the last of the page?

Comment: @SatyaShot If you want this to append at a particular point - is there an element you can use to place it adjacent to or inside? Or is it literally going within the body element and has no sibling elements?

Comment: this is like an sort of a widget, any body can insert this piece of code anywhere they want.  this is the widget := <script type="text/javascript">
    var hashgurus_woeid = 1;
</script>
<script async src="../feed/livetrend.js"></script>

Comment: I have seen many widgets like google analytics or google ads. I am not sure how they exactly place. may be there must be a logic which I am trying to decode but stuck!

Comment: @SatyaShot I'd suggest adding an ID to the script element that calls your live trend script file then - and inserting the created element **before or after that** as per bobdye's edit. Use of document.write is bad practice for a number of reasons - and completely incompatible with the async attribute - for reasons that are listed at http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Comment: I can always add a <div id=someid> to the widget and i can set the innerhtml of the someid to what i want. I know this will work but can this be acheiveed by just the script tags alone???

Comment: I added an id to script tag  <script id="someid" type="text/javascript">
    var hashgurus_woeid = 1;
</script>
<script async src="../feed/livetrend.js"></script> and this works.This is acheived by having two script tags. the first script tag with the id and the next script tag is actually the widget. am i rite?

Comment: thanks bobdye. your answers certainly helped me a lot!

Comment: @SatyaShot I have taken the liberty of tweaking bobdye's answer to remove the need for the second script element, and to insert the required HTML at the point of the remaining script element. It should also work with the async attribute now.

Comment: @pwdst Now i get a strange problem where if i put the widget twice it gives me only for once as the id becomes the same.  I have put in another post for this problem [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619477/javascript-widget-async-two-widgets-gets-mixed

Comment: Here as per your code i want the id itself to be generic and passed to .js file. is that possible?